# How to set the speed of the smooth scrolling with CSS?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'd like to scroll to the bottom of the page and I recently found the scroll behavior style tag. Is there a way to change the speed of smooth scrolling using a CSS style?

Related question (using JQuery):
[How to change speed of a smooth scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360146/how-to-change-speed-of-a-smooth-scroll)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the smooth scrolling speed cannot be changed using CSS. The only attribute tags available are behavior tags; smooth/auto.